# How to create a hidden folder i.e .MyFolder [(dot)MyFolder] in DCIM directory (Scoped Storage) Android Q

Tags: java, android, file, mediastore, hidden-files

I want to create a hidden folder i.e  .MyFolder [(dot)MyFolder]  in DCIM directory. Here is my code:-

```
final String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM+File.separator+".MyFolder/images";
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,positionOfPager+".jpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE,"image/*");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,relativeLocation);
        imageUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
        fos = (FileOutputStream) context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,fos);
```

The problem here is that a folder is create with Hyphen symbol "_.MyFolder" i.e.[(Hypen)(dot)MyFolder] due to which the folder is not hidden. My app is creating lots of images which i dont want to show up in gallery to bother the user. Please help me out
Note:- I am implementing the code for scoped storage android 11

Comment: "My app is creating lots of images which i dont want to show up in gallery to bother the user" -- then put them in `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFilesDir()` (methods on `Context`).

Comment: `My app is creating lots of images which i dont want to show up in gallery` Well then dont use the MediaStore to begin with. But even where you can create such a '.hidden' folder there with mkdir() and place your files in it  in the old way the MediaStore will soon scan those files in them.

Comment: thanks. Now I am storing the images in app specific folder :)

Comment: i am facing the same problem. whenever i create, it create with hyphen symbol "_.test".

Comment: Can you put a debug point on the `relativeLocation` line, and check what the relative location value is being set after execution of that line?

Comment: `(Scoped Storage) Android Q` Q==10. AND `am implementing the code for scoped storage android 11` do not match.

Comment: Hmmm.. with 21 points i'm amazed you can offer a 50 points bounty..

Answer (score 1):

```
File file = new File( 
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), ".MyFolder/images");

if ( ! file.existst() )
    if ( !file.mkdirs() )
         return;
```

Both on 10 and 11 you can use this code.

You can also create your files in this folder using classic file system paths.

No need for MediaStore. Worse: As soon as you use the MediaStore the MediaStore knows about your files and hence Gallery apps that use the MediaStore to list files.

For an Android Q device add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to application tag in manifest file.

But.... this hidden folder stuff will not prevent the media scanner to scan your files after some time. Also a `.nomedia` file will often not do now adays.

Comment: any idea how can i add .nomedia file to prevent media comes on gallery apps?

Comment: No. Sorry. I'm a victim too.